# Integrate using gamma and beta function.

Tags: integration, gamma-function, beta-function

As homework, I have to solve this integral using the gamma and beta functions. I was unable to find it online, so could anyone help me?
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-1}\ln^{2}{x}dx, {\alpha}< {0}
$$

I have tried the following substitutions until now:
$$
t=\ln{x};t=\ln{(1-x)}; t=\ln{(1/x)}; t=\ln{(x+1)} 
$$

I got stuck either at ln(0) or when I had to find a function that can be transformed to the gamma function.

This is the beta function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function
And this is the gamma function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: When you couldn't find it online, another option is also to try it yourself.

Comment: I did, but I could find no substitution to help me out.

Comment: What substitutions did you try? Show us what you tried, give us a reason to trust you.

Comment: What is the integral representation of the beta and gamma functions ? Just asking for it is a big hint

Comment: Done, I updated my question to answer both of you.

Comment: @CatalinCatalin, just saying that you tried these substitutions is not enough. Show us your work, show what form of the integrand you got after that substitution and in which step you got stuck.

Comment: @CatalinCatalin I think there's been a mistake, the integrand isn't bounded so it's not integrable. Are you sure the lower bound is correct? I suspect it's probably a $1$.

Comment: The divergence can also be motivated by comparing the integral $\int_0^{\frac{1}{e}} x^{-2}\ln^2 x dx$ to $\int_0^{\frac{1}{e}} \frac{1}{x^2} dx.$

Comment: Write us down what do you get if you substitute $x=e^t$.